# Datastax studio cannot read schema for graph

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph, datastax-studio

I have a DSE 6 Cluster in production, everything works great.

Lately I wanted to plug the version 6 of datastax studio on it.

I configured the connection properly with ssl and authentication and the connection test is successful.

The problem is that DSE Studio doesn't seem to be able to get the schema from the server.

I'm using the last java version from Oracle, and I configured JCE with jce unlimited strength jurisdiction policy files for java 8.

I have this error in the studio log:

```
23:02:22.740 [Studio-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12] ERROR 

com.datastax.studio.client.SchemaManager ID:  TS: - Unexpected exception getting cql schema for connection null: java.lang.NullPointerException
23:02:22.744 [Studio-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-42] WARN  com.datastax.studio.streaming.websocket.CQLSchemaBroadcaster ID:  TS: - Schema stream provider got null cql schema
23:02:22.740 [Studio-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-32] ERROR com.datastax.studio.application.EventuateEventBus ID:  TS: - Unhandled exception during publishing (event=SparkSQLConnectionClosed(connectionId=null), listener=com.datastax.studio.client.SchemaManager$$Lambda$71/1502197135@4121ef79):
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.replaceNode(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1106) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1097) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at com.datastax.studio.client.SchemaManager.stopSparkSqlSchemaRefresh(SchemaManager.java:473) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.datastax.studio.client.SchemaManager.lambda$init$5(SchemaManager.java:181) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.datastax.studio.application.EventuateEventBus$EventListenerActor.lambda$new$0(EventuateEventBus.java:116) ~[classes/:?]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123) [scala-library-2.11.8.jar:?]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167) [scala-library-2.11.8.jar:?]
    at com.rbmhtechnology.eventuate.EventsourcedView$class.receiveEvent(EventsourcedView.scala:227) [eventuate-core_2.11-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
    at com.rbmhtechnology.eventuate.AbstractEventsourcedActor.com$rbmhtechnology$eventuate$ConfirmedDelivery$$super$receiveEvent(AbstractEventsourcedActor.scala:32) [eventuate-core_2.11-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
    at com.rbmhtechnology.eventuate.ConfirmedDelivery$class.receiveEvent(ConfirmedDelivery.scala:83) [eventuate-core_2.11-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
    at com.rbmhtechnology.eventuate.AbstractEventsourcedActor.com$rbmhtechnology$eventuate$PersistOnEvent$$super$receiveEvent(AbstractEventsourcedActor.scala:32) [eventuate-core_2.11-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
    at com.rbmhtechnology.eventuate.PersistOnEvent$class.receiveEvent(PersistOnEvent.scala:79) [eventuate-core_2.11-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
    at com.rbmhtechnology.eventuate.AbstractEventsourcedActor.receiveEvent(AbstractEventsourcedActor.scala:32) [eventuate-core_2.11-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
    at com.rbmhtechnology.eventuate.EventsourcedView$$anonfun$initiated$1.applyOrElse(EventsourcedView.scala:457) [eventuate-core_2.11-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:497) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at com.rbmhtechnology.eventuate.AbstractEventsourcedView.aroundReceive(AbstractEventsourcedView.scala:55) [eventuate-core_2.11-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.17.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.11.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.11.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.11.8.jar:?]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.11.8.jar:?]
```

On the server side there is nothing special in the logs.

Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: This is Studio 6.0.0 (GA, not EAP, right?) with a connection config setup with SSL and auth, and the connection test is working, correct?

What happens when you open a Notebook using this Connection config? Is the connection successful, or is there any error banner? Is it possible to execute statements in a CQL cell?

The description says that Studio is unable to read the schema - does that mean that the Schema View does not show any results?

The errors in the log are reporting a `null` studio connection id; that shouldn't happen, of course. Have connection configs been deleted?

Comment: When I open a notebook I see the error banner, it prompts me to select a graph but displays none, only the option to create a new one. The schema view does not show any result.

Comment: What is the message in the error banner? Is it "Graph does not exist" or something else? Does the studio.log contain any messages about the "Graph Analytics Server host"? The error you posted may be unrelated - it's sounding like the CQL connection works with SSL/auth but maybe the gremlin server connection is not working.